# css: how to make this render cross browser?

Tags: html, css

the page loads fine on google chrome browser but on firefox or IE, the elements does not appear to show up properly, wondering what's going on.

http://jsfiddle.net/xjL6puez/

```
#DIV_1 {
    bottom: 0px;
    color: rgb(31, 44, 51);
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1920px;
    z-index: 200;
    align-self: stretch;
    perspective-origin: 960px 315px;
    transform-origin: 960px 315px;
    background: rgb(67, 67, 67) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(31, 44, 51);
    font: normal normal normal normal 12px/normal 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', 'lucida grande', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(31, 44, 51) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_1*/

#HEADER_2 {
    color: rgb(31, 44, 51);
    height: 56px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1919px;
    z-index: 50;
    align-self: stretch;
    perspective-origin: 960px 28px;
    transform-origin: 960px 28px;
    background: rgb(175, 224, 233) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border-top: 0px none rgb(31, 44, 51);
    border-right: 0px none rgb(31, 44, 51);
    border-bottom: 0px none rgb(31, 44, 51);
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(53, 53, 53);
    font: normal normal normal normal 12px/normal 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', 'lucida grande', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(31, 44, 51) none 0px;
}/*#HEADER_2*/
```

Comment: I have broke elements in both IE and chrome.

Comment: 1033 lines of css for such a simple page Oo? I don't think that it will be likely that someone will check such a large `html` and `css` code for a mistake.

Comment: So many unnecessary, often conflicting lines, that looks as if it was generated in several CSS IDEs, at once.